# How to get a chain of nodes (Neo4j) with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I have several NodeEntity classes, and they have relationships with each other:

```
@NodeEntity
data class Person(
        ...
        @Relationship(type = "OWNS")
        var places: MutableSet<Place> = HashSet(),
)

@NodeEntity
data class Place(
        ...

        @Relationship(type = "OWNS")
        var rooms: MutableSet<Room> = HashSet()
)

@NodeEntity
data class Room(...)
```

Also, I use `Neo4jRepository` to work with the database.

For example, I have a person with one place with two rooms. When I get a place, I can see these rooms. But when I get a person, I see only places with an empty set instead of rooms.

Why does this happen? Turns out Neo4j returns only one relationship?

Should I override some Neo4jRepository methods with `@Query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading from the database, neoj4 has a concept of *depth*, which represents the number of relationships to traverse when reading. To read more nodes, increase the value of the depth argument.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Neo4jRepository allow to use standard methods like `findAll()`, `findById()` and `save()` with `int depth` parameter and other methods with `@Depth(int value)` annotation.